# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar csrf en livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Antes en laravel se podía poner @csrf despues del inicio de form yo encontré un wizard o step con laravel 8 y livewire, estuve analizando a detalle la función de cada paso, pero encontré una gran duda no hay etiquetas form de apertura ni cierre y no sé donde colocar la protección csrf.

El modelo es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'amount', 'description', 'status', 'stock'
];
}
```

En la siguiente ruta app/Http/Livewire/Wizard.php tengo el siguiente archivo con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;

class Wizard extends Component
{
public $currentStep = 1;
public $name, $amount, $description, $status = 1, $stock;
public $successMessage = '';

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.wizard');
}

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function firstStepSubmit()
{
    $validatedData = $this->validate([
        'name' => 'required|unique:products',
        'amount' => 'required|numeric',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $this->currentStep = 2;
}

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function secondStepSubmit()
{
    $validatedData = $this->validate([
        'stock' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
    ]);

    $this->currentStep = 3;
}

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function submitForm()
{
    Product::create([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'amount' => $this->amount,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'stock' => $this->stock,
        'status' => $this->status,
    ]);

    $this->successMessage = 'Product Created Successfully.';

    $this->clearForm();

    $this->currentStep = 1;
}

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function back($step)
{
    $this->currentStep = $step;    
}

/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function clearForm()
{
    $this->name = '';
    $this->amount = '';
    $this->description = '';
    $this->stock = '';
    $this->status = 1;
}
}
```

En la vistas tengo el siguiente código que es digamos que los pasos (step) con cada campo del wizard:

```
<div>

 @if(!empty($successMessage))
<div class="alert alert-success">
 {{ $successMessage }}
 </div>
 @endif

<div class="stepwizard">
<div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-circle {{ $currentStep != 1 ? 'btn- 
  default' : 'btn-primary' }}">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-circle {{ $currentStep != 2 ? 'btn- 
  default' : 'btn-primary' }}">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-circle {{ $currentStep != 3 ? 'btn- 
 default' : 'btn-primary' }}" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Step 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row setup-content {{ $currentStep != 1 ? 'displayNone' : '' }}" id="step-1">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Step 1</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Product Name:</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="name" class="form-control" id="taskTitle">
                @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Product Amount:</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="amount" class="form-control" 
    id="productAmount"/>
                @error('amount') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Product Description:</label>
                <textarea type="text" wire:model="description" class="form-control" 
     id="taskDescription">{{{ $description ?? '' }}}</textarea>
                @error('description') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" 
   wire:click="firstStepSubmit" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row setup-content {{ $currentStep != 2 ? 'displayNone' : '' }}" id="step-2">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Step 2</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Product Status</label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" wire:model="status" 
    value="1" {{{ $status == '1' ? "checked" : "" }}}> Active</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" wire:model="status" 
    value="0" {{{ $status == '0' ? "checked" : "" }}}> DeActive</label>
                @error('status') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Product Stock</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="stock" class="form-control" 
   id="productAmount"/>
                @error('stock') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" 
   wire:click="secondStepSubmit">Next</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" 
  wire:click="back(1)">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row setup-content {{ $currentStep != 3 ? 'displayNone' : '' }}" id="step-3">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Step 3</h3>

            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Name:</td>
                    <td><strong>{{$name}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Amount:</td>
                    <td><strong>{{$amount}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product status:</td>
                    <td><strong>{{$status ? 'Active' : 'DeActive'}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Description:</td>
                    <td><strong>{{$description}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Stock:</td>
                    <td><strong>{{$stock}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" wire:click="submitForm" 
    type="button">Finish!</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" 
 wire:click="back(2)">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

por ultimo tengo lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Laravel Livewire Example - ItSolutionStuff.com</title>
@livewireStyles
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="{{ asset('wizard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Wizard o step formulario
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <livewire:wizard />
  </div>
</div>
    
 </div>

 </body>

 @livewireScripts

 </html>
```

La única idea fue colocar lo siguiente en en el archivo wizard.blade.php despues del primer DIV @csrf y en el ultimo submit de Finish! lo siguiente name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"

¿Cómo saber si está bien la protección de @csrf?

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios relevantes:

- En los componentes de *Livewire* todas las propiedades declaradas como públicas estarán automáticamente disponibles al *front* **ojo con eso**
- La documentación no menciona (*o al menos no lo he visto*) el uso explícito o necesario de un token al estilo de Laravel con la directiva **`@csrf`** por ejemplo, pero....

  - Lo que si hace es que por cada *petición* anexará al *payload* de la misma un *checksum* con una estructura como la siguiente:

    ```
      checksum: "200ef..90b17d......................................"
      data: {propiedadModelo: []}
      dataMeta: {models: {propiedadModelo: {............................................}}}
      htmlHash: "77b6..........."
    ```

Donde:

- Si un *hash* del payload no coincidiera con el *checksum* entonces arrojaría un error.

Eso es por un lado, sin embargo te invito a **que revises la documentación en el enlace provisto al final** para profundizar mas en los siguientes temas:

- Ciclo de vida de los componentes (*los diagramas son muy explicativos*)
- El segundo factor que dicho framework tiene presente para temas de seguridad

Te invito a que revises mas a detalle el código fuente de esta herramienta a través de las siguientes clases:

- `app\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\HydrationMiddleware.php`

**Referencias**

- [Livewire security](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/security)